# writing a dll in Visual Studio in C (not C++) causing unresolved symbols

Tags: c, visual-studio, dll, jna

I've been going through the dll walkthrough on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636(VS.80).aspx) and it works fine. I then removed all the C++ style code in the dll and replaced it with the C equivalent, and it still works.

BUT, when I rename the file from X.cpp to X.c (which I guess causes compilation in C-mode), I get error LNK2019 (unresolved external symbol) for every function in the dll. For my purposes it's essential that the dll be in C not C++ because that's what Java Native Access supports.

Here's the header of the dll:

```
__declspec(dllexport) double Add(double a, double b);
__declspec(dllexport) double Subtract(double a, double b);
__declspec(dllexport) double Multiply(double a, double b);
__declspec(dllexport) double Divide(double a, double b);
```

Here's the body of the (C++) testing program that uses the dll:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MyMathFuncs.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double a = 7.4;
    int b = 99;

    cout << "a + b = " <<
        Add(a, b) << endl;
    cout << "a - b = " <<
        Subtract(a, b) << endl;
    cout << "a * b = " <<
        Multiply(a, b) << endl;
    cout << "a / b = " <<
        Divide(a, b) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

(Just to clarify it's fine that the testing program is in C++; it's only the dll I'm trying to compile in C).

Comment: post MyFuncs.h please (quick question, you did use extern "C" ... correct?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
extern "C"
{
#include "MyMathFuncs.h"
}
```

Comment: or better put the extern "C" in the header file

Comment: Yes, you can do the #ifdef __cplusplus extern "C" thing in the header

Comment: Awesome thank you! The file does now compile with the dll source file called X.c.
And yet JNA still can't load the dll correctly :(
I'll post that as a separate issue when I have more information.

Answer (score 1):

After you changed the extension, you are now using the wrong names in the client code.  Those names are no longer decorated as they were when you compiled it as C++ code.  The proper way to export names like this, so that those decorations are never used and you don't depend on the language:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
double Add(double a, double b);
```

To see the exported names, use Dumpbin.exe /exports on your DLL.